# restoring back suspended Android app

Tags: google-play

my App was suspended on the google play for minor issue regarding mining option which was removed months ago, as my app didn't do any actually mining.

I decided to remove completely that feature but the app has been suspended what s the fast way to get google support to help with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your app was suspended for good reason if it had potential security issues...don't hold your breath on it being added back to the store.

Comment: the App did absolutely nothing, i removed all non-complaint codes.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to contact Google Play support is via the help option "?" question mark icon in the Play Console.